# Recreating the Functor type in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm wanting to make the Functor type in Swift as a protocol, but I'm having trouble with the type clauses.

```
protocol Functor {
    typealias A
    func fmap<
        B, C
        where
        C == Self
        C.A == B>
        (A -> B) -> C
}
```

The problem is that C == Self sort of implies that C is the same as Self, and therefore has the same A. Is there any way to define a generic that is the same type but with a different type parameter?

EDIT: Maybe I should clarify that the goal here is to function like fmap in other functional languages, except self is the in parameter, instead of fmap being a global function that takes an in parameter.

Answer (score 4):

No, not today. Swift lacks higher-kinded types. It doesn't even have support for first-order types. So as a first step, you'd want to be able to talk about `let x: Array<_>` where you didn't yet know the type of the contained object. Swift can't handle that. It can't handle generic closures, either. For example:

```
func firstT<T>(xs: [T]) -> T {
    return xs[0]
}
let ft = firstT // "Argument for generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"
```

Those are the simple cases, and Swift's type system already starts falling apart (it can handle it as a function definition, but not as a type). Swift's type system completely falls apart when asked to represent higher-kinded types like Functor.

A little deeper discussion of the issue (but mostly reiterates what I've said here: https://gist.github.com/rnapier/5a84f65886e1ee40f62e)

Note that this isn't specifically a feature so much of "other functional languages." First, Swift isn't really a functional language; it just has some functional features, and second, not all functional languages have this feature (Haskell and Scala, yes, ML and LISP, no). The feature you want is higher-kinded types, and that can exist with or without other functional features.

A nice intro to this is available in section 4.3 Higher-kinded types of [Scala for generic programmers](http://ropas.snu.ac.kr/~bruno/papers/ScalaGeneric.pdf). Swift has some very interesting similarities to Scala, so the history of Scala can provide some hints about what might make sense for Swift (Higher-kinded types didn't show up until Scala 2.5).

Comment: thanks for your response here, i learnt a lot. the scala link no longer works but it seems the wayback machine has a copy https://web.archive.org/web/20170810124742/http://ropas.snu.ac.kr/%7Ebruno/papers/ScalaGeneric.pdf